# How to enable outside connection before submit Pyspark job to Dataproc

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, jdbc, dataproc

I have a Pyspark file which will be submitted to Dataproc.

```py
try:
    print("Start writing")
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://some-ip:5432/postgres"
    properties = {
        "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
        "user": "postgres",
        "password": "root"
    }
    df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="result", mode="overwrite", properties=properties)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sc.stop()
```

I use postgresql-42.6.0.jar JDBC driver and my database is postgresql 14.

Here is the error.

```
An error occurred while calling o86.jdbc.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
...
```

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
...
```

Here is how I submit my job through google cloud shell

```
gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://taro-de-intern/pyspark_postgresql.py\
  --cluster my-cluster \
  --jars gs://my-bucket/postgresql-42.6.0.jar
```

I suspect that it has something to do with driver so I downgrade my jar file version to 42.4.2.
But it didn't work and yield the same error.

I even tried to change the format to

```py
df.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
.option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://some-ip:5432/postgres") \
.option("dbtable", "schema.result") \
.option("user", "postgres") \
.option("password", "root") \
.save()
```

also yield the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already sort it out so here is the solution.
If you are using any cloud database(SQL instance on GCP, AWS, Azure)

***Don't forget to allow outside connection***

Here is where you can enable outside connection on GCP cloud SQL instance.

1. Go to edit in your SQL instance overview
   [image]
2. Go to connections
3. Add network(You won't have the allow all network when you first open) by entering the name of your connection(name doesn't matter) and your [IP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmkBVj0XHcg&pp=ygUWaG93IHRvIGZpbmQgaXAgYWRkcmVzcw%3D%3D) [address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcpip-addressing-and-subnetting).

   For more information please visit Microsoft website on subnet mask.

   **Note:** This is for the sake of example so don't allow all connection (0.0.0.0) in the real production.

   [image]
4. Scroll down to the bottom and click save.